# Spivak Calculus Chapter 1 Question 19(a)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to prove Schwarz inequality from : $(\lambda y_1-x_1)^2+(\lambda y_2-x_2)^2>0$, such that $\lambda y_1≠x_1$ and $\lambda y_2≠x_2$
This is fairly simple by using question's 18 fact: If $x^2+bx+c>0$ for all $x$, then $b^2-4c<0$.
Using these two I arrived at $x_1y_1+x_2y_2< \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2}$, but the Schwarz inequality presented in the book is:
$$x_1y_1+x_2y_2\le \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2}$$
I'm not sure how the operator $\le$ replaces my $<$ here.

Comment: minor correction: you've made a typo since there's no $x_2$ on the RHS of your inequations

Comment: In the first line a square is missing and you don't have $>0$. You only have $ \geq 0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I fixed the square, but in the book, $> 0$ is mentioned

Comment: It is wrong. The mistake is in this very first line. There is no reason why you have $>0$ in this line.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy that's what Spivak's used in the book

Comment: Could be a typo.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy it's not because he also mentions $\lambda y_1 ≠ x_1$ and $\lambda y_2 ≠ x_2$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109090/discussion-between-richard-and-kavi-rama-murthy).

Comment: Strict inequality you have proved is correct under the assumption in the first line. You have to consider the remaining case where you get equality.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have proven $a < b$, then you've also proven $a \le b$. So that would answer your question.
2. However, you must've made some mistake because you actually can't always have strict inequality. Consider $$x_1 = x_2 = y_1 = y_2 = 1.$$

---

**EDIT:** The question now mentions that $\lambda y_1 \neq x_1$ and $\lambda y_2 \neq x_2$.
What I suspect Spivak really means is that the following equality:
$$(x_1, x_2) = \lambda (y_1, y_2)$$
does not hold for *any* $\lambda \in \Bbb R$.

In this case, you would indeed the first strict inequality that you write in your question. (Note that you only need one of $\lambda_iy_i - x_i$ to be nonzero.)

That leads you to
$$\lambda(y_1^2 + y_2^2) - 2\lambda(x_1x_2 + y_1y_2) + (x_1^2 + x_2^2) > 0.$$

Now, I know that you would proceed to write $b^2 < 4ac$ but you cannot do that for the leading coefficient in the above need not be nonzero. (That is, the above need not be a quadratic and you can't use that.)

However, that is possible only in the case $y_1 = y_2 = 0$ and that in the case, equality does indeed hold.

For example, take $$x_1 = x_2 = 1, \; y_1 = y_2 = 0$$
to see that you still need to allow equality.

Comment: This is at best a comment. Find the mistake and let OP know where the mistake lies.

Comment: I have updated my question. Apparently the new condition forbids step 2

Comment: @Richard: I have now updated my answer. You still need to allow equality.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I'm not sure I agree. The OP's primary question seemed to how one can conclude "$A \le B$" given "$A < B$". (That is, more of a logic question.) I didn't really see proving the correct Cauchy Schwarz as the main issue which is why I just pointed out that there's a possible flaw. In any case, I have now updated it completely filling in a step I have to guess OP made.

Comment: In the Fourth Edition, the sentence reads ( as correctly suspected)....."Now suppose  $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ are both not $0$, and that there is no number $\lambda$ such that $x_{1} = \lambda y_{1}$ and  $x_{2} = \lambda y_{2}$"  But the words 'no' and 'number' are on different pages, hence perhaps the confusion.